# Custom UIView via UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to modify a UIActionSheet with a custom UIView? I have a preferences cell in one of my tables which would benefit greatly from a modal window appearing with a UIDatePicker. Having it appear as an Alert would be fantastic as well. Ideally it would be nice to get the free animation that comes in play with UIActionSheet. Otherwise it's a matter of creating a UIView, setting a custom background, adding a UIDatePicker, and animating it manually.

Is there a smarter/faster way to do this than replicating a lot of functionality which Apple usually gives you out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

UIActionSheet is a UIView. You should be able to add in other views into its subviews.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup for anyone happening upon this question, modifying the UIActionSheet is not supported by Apple.  Apps that do so will most likely break at major os updates.